# Yii2: How to display dropDown names in update/insert form also in view?

Tags: php, activerecord, yii2, activemodel

I am developing an application in Yii2. I made the form with the following dropdown structure:

```
<!-- Konténer típus -->
        <?= $form->field($model, 'kontener_tipus_id')
                ->dropDownList(
                    ArrayHelper::map(KontenerTipus::find()->AsArray()->all(), 'id',
                        function($model, $defaultValue) {
                            if ($model['tipus'] == "N") { $tipus = "Nyitott"; } else { $tipus = "Zárt"; };
                            if ($model['forma'] == "S") { $forma = "Szimmetrikus forma"; } else { $forma = "Aszimmetrikus forma"; };
                            if ($model['lancos'] == 0) { $lancos = "Láncos"; } else { $lancos = "Nem láncos"; };
                            if ($model['teto'] == "B") { $teto = "Billenő tetős"; } else { $teto = "Pille tetős"; };


                            return $tipus . " - " . $forma . " - " . $lancos . " - " . $teto;
                        }
                    )
                )
                ->label('Konténer típus');
        ?>
```

In the "SingleView" view file I want to print out the same result.

```
<?= DetailView::widget([
        'model' => $model,
        'attributes' => [
            'id',
            'kod',
            'nev',
            'cim',
            'kihelyezes_datuma',
            'lng',
            'lat',
            ['attribute' => 'sajat', 'value' => $model->getSajat()],
            //Konténer típushoz tartozó tulajdonságok megjelenítése
            ['attribute' => 'kontener_tipus_id', 'value' => 11]
        ],
    ]) ?>
```

I tried to write a function into the value section but it gave me an error: "HTML special chars got an object input".

What do you think is the most simple way to do that?

Comment: `I tried to write a function into the value section but it gave me an error` - could you post this function's code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function is not allowed. But the final value can be assigned:

```
<?= DetailView::widget([
    'model' => $model,
    'attributes' => [
        'id',
        'kod',
        'nev',
        'cim',
        'kihelyezes_datuma',
        'lng',
        'lat',
        ['attribute' => 'sajat', 'value' => $model->getSajat()],
        //Konténer típushoz tartozó tulajdonságok megjelenítése
        ['attribute' => 'kontener_tipus_id', 'value' => 
            ($model['tipus']  == "N" ? "Nyitott" : "Zárt") . ' - ' . 
            ($model['forma']  == "S" ? "Szimmetrikus forma" : "Aszimmetrikus forma") . ' - ' . 
            ($model['lancos'] ==  0  ? "Láncos" : "Nem láncos") . ' - ' . 
            ($model['teto']   == "B" ? "Billenő tetős" : "Pille tetős")  
        ]
    ],
]) ?>
```

---

**Better solution:**

Of course you can put the creation of the string into an own model method

```
class KontenerTipus extends Model // or ActiveRecord....
    ...
    public function getKonténerTípus() {
        return
            ($this->tipus  == "N" ? "Nyitott" : "Zárt") . ' - ' . 
            ($this->forma  == "S" ? "Szimmetrikus forma" : "Aszimmetrikus forma") . ' - ' . 
            ($this->lancos ==  0  ? "Láncos" : "Nem láncos") . ' - ' . 
            ($this->teto   == "B" ? "Billenő tetős" : "Pille tetős")  
    }
    ....
}
```

or in a helper function somehwere. This method could be reused in the form:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'kontener_tipus_id')
    ->dropDownList(
        ArrayHelper::map(KontenerTipus::find()->AsArray()->all(), 'id', 'konténerTípus')
    )
    ->label('Konténer típus');
?>
```

and in the single model view:

```
DetailView::widget([
    'model' => $model,
    'attributes' => [
        'id',
        'kod',
        'nev',
        'cim',
        'kihelyezes_datuma',
        'lng',
        'lat',
        ['attribute' => 'sajat', 'value' => $model->getSajat()],
        //Konténer típushoz tartozó tulajdonságok megjelenítése
        'konténerTípus',
    ],
])
```

Comment: Thank you, I made some changes in the view file following the instructions you gave and figured it out.

Comment: @Gabesz I've updated my answer. Have a look if this makes sense to you.